# Use a character to look ahead, but only when it exists

Tags: regex

Suppose I have these line:

```
/path-to-something/section/resource?var=name
/path-to-something/section/resource
```

I want to use regular expression to capture the text between /path-to-something/ and the ? sign. So for both cases, I want the output to be:

```
section/resource
```

The farthest I can go is to use this regex:

```
(?<=/path-to-something/).+(?=\?)
```

But it fails for the second case (where the URL doesn't have the ? sign):

```
section/resource
[no match]
```

Is there a way to do something like this in Regular Expression? I know I can do this without regular expression, but I wanted to know if this is possible to do in regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
(?<=/path-to-something/)[^?]+
```

Comment: That works! I'm still wondering how it did it though. Can you explain the logic?

Comment: @Ricky: `[^?]+` is a negated character class that means "look for one or more characters that aren't `?`". It stops when it encounters a `?`.